# What type of hubs attach on only one side?

Tags: wheels, hub, tricycle

I wish to build a tricycle and one of the limiting factors is getting the front hubs. I search for tricycle hubs on eBay and get nothing useful.
I need both the hub and axle or the axle dimension has to be a very common easily obtained bolt size.
What would I search for?

Comment: I posted the appropriate axle on the other thread where you asked this question in a comment.. The issue is that each brand with have different struts and steering rack setups. If you are attempting to build one from scratch it will be a challenge.

Axle: http://www.jbi.bike/web/checking_product_description.php?part_number=38883

Hub:http://www.jbi.bike/web/checking_product_description.php?part_number=38751 (36 hole, 6 bolt disc, with bearing)

Comment: You asked a very similar question 20 hours ago.  Give it a couple days.

Answer (score 2):

I think wheel chair hubs are what you are looking for. If you need disk brakes, Cannondale Lefty hubs are another off the shelf solution.